# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'student'.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried rewrite other ways but the code always showing error like this

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'student'

The error occurs on the line

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I hope someone will be able to help.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (StudUsn.Text == "" || StudName.Text == "" || 
        FatherName.Text == "" || MotherName.Text == "" ||
        AddressTb.Text == "" || CollegeTb.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No empty filled accepted");
    }
    else
    {
        Con.Open();

        String query = "insert into Student_tbl values(" + StudUsn.Text + ",'" + FatherName.Text + "','" + MotherName.Text + "','" + AddressTb.Text + "','" + CollegeTb.Text + "','" + StudRoomCb + "','" + StudStatusCb + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Student successfully added");

        Con.Close();

        updateBookedStatus();
        FillStudentDGV();
        FillStudentCombobox();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use SQLParameters.  Always.  And create use and dispose of connections as needed.  Never reuse a global one.  Ever.  You are also not controlling which values go into which columns.

Comment: You should NOT do string concatenation to build your SQL query, that leads to two things: Bugs like the one you are having, and a security vulnerability called SQL Injection, one funny example is [bobby tables](https://bobby-tables.com/). Use parametrized queries instead

Comment: @Cleptus thanks for your answer, can u send link for parametrized sql, i mean some arcticles

Comment: There are literally **GAZILLIONS** of articles and blog posts on this - just **search!** See e.g. https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx or https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Comment: don't do inline sql like this, but issue is with single and double quotes

Comment: Have you tried inspectin the actual value of `query` and executing that query for instance in SQL Server Management Studio? That might give you a hint on what's going wrong with your approach of constructing queries. Use parametrized queries, that will get rid of many problems (mysterious syntax errors, security issues, ...9

Comment: 'Con.Open();
                var query = @"insert into Student_tbl value StudUsn=@sn, FatherName=@fn, MotherName=@mn, AdressTb=@at, CollegeTb=@ct, StudRoomCb=@sr,StudStatusCb=@ss";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,Con);
                string sn = null;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@sn, StudName.Text);
                string fn = null;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@fn, FatherName.Text);'                          i have tried this but the error still the same with value

Comment: First of all such updated info belongs into the question (via edit) and not in the comments. Second, what sort of `insert` query is that??? Have you tried reading one of the linked resources? Where did you find a syntax like that?

Comment: You also need to dispose your connection and command objects with `using`, do *not* cache your connection

Answer (score 0):

The following shows how to insert a record into a database using parameters. The number of rows affected will be returned (ie: 0 means the row wasn't inserted and 1 means the row was inserted successfully).

```
private int TblStudentInsert(string studentUsn, string fatherName, string motherName, string streetAddress, string college, string studentRoom, string studentStatus)
{
    string sqlText = "INSERT INTO Student (StudentUsn, FatherName, MotherName, StreetAddress, College, StudentRoom, StudentStatus) VALUES (@studentUsn, @fatherName, @motherName, @streetAddress, @college, @studentRoom, @studentStatus);";
    
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_connectionStr))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlText, con))
        {
            //add parameters
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentUsn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentUsn;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@fatherName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fatherName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@motherName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = motherName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@streetAddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = streetAddress;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@college", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = college;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentRoom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentRoom;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentStatus", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = studentStatus;

            //execute and return number of rows affected
            return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: For Unicode, use `NVarChar` instead of `VarChar`. If inserting a null value, use `DBNull.Value`.

**Resources**:

- [SqlConnection Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlCommand Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=netframework-4.8)
- [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8)
- [DBNull Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dbnull?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score -1):

This syntax error is caused by a trailing comma as if you run the debugger and evaluate it, this will be in the format of `INSERT INTO Student_tbl VALUES (N'xyz')`. You just need to remove the concatenation and use parameters for these values.

Try this one

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Student_tbl (StudUsn, StudName,FatherName,MotherName,AddressTb,CollegeTb) VALUES (@StudUsn, StudName,@FatherName,@MotherName,@AddressTb,@CollegeTb);";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudUsn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StudUsn.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StudName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = StudName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FatherName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = FatherName.Text;
//.
//.
//so on and so forth
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

insert into Student_tbl (this name should be matched with your sql table columns) ........

Comment: And... https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/

Comment: Please don't recommend `AddWithValue` https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: That's true. updating my answer

Comment: @DaleK explained